# SharePoint shared service with same database alias

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, sql-alias

I have SP2016 and SP2013 On-Premises farms. I would like to consume User Profile Application from SP2016 on SP2013. All the configuration was done successfully but I have SQLAlias with same name (alias name) on both SP2016 and SP2013 Farms, but pointing to a different SQL instances. I am getting an error since SP2013 UPA (consumer) is trying to find the Profile_DB on SP2013's SQL Server instead of SP2016's SQL instance. 
Is there any workaround without updating SQLAlias at all?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint will always call the alias. Because the reference databases (publisher farm) has the same alias, when the consumer farm looks for the Profile database, as an example, it will make a call to the SQL Server used by the Profile database. Because the Profile database is using the alias, ultimately the consumer farm will end up calling it's own SQL Server rather than the SQL Server where the database is hosted.

While you can certainly change the alias for all databases sans the Admin/Config databases of a farm, that is an option but if I recall calls are still made by the consumer farm to the Config database of the publishing farm.

The solution here would be to rebuild one or the other farms using a different alias. If you're using SQL Server AOAG, do not use an alias.

Comment: Without rebuilding the farm can we update the SQLAlias name on the publisher farm? for ex: I'll rename DB server using Rename-SPServer and then run psconfig.. will this work?

Comment: You cannot change the name of where the Config and Admin database point to. In order to change the name (e.g. adjust the SQL Alias or change the SQL Servers actual name) where the Config/Admin database reside, you must rebuild the farm.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can I go for unsupported version of updating the regkey of the ConfigDB to point to new SQLAlias? do you envision any complications with this approach?

Comment: No, that won't work. The registry isn't the only location the SQL Server is referenced.

Comment: Rename-SPServer with old sql alias to new sql alias followed by iisreset and clear cache actually worked to me.. it even updated the config db connection string on registry too.. I do not see any issue while accessing the sites.. Do you see any issues with this approach?